# Julia: creating a method for Any vector with missing values

Tags: function, methods, julia, missing-data, dispatch

I would like to create a function that deals with missing values. However, when I tried to specify the missing type Array{Missing, 1}, it errors.

```
function f(x::Array{<:Number, 1})
    # do something complicated
    println("no missings.")
    println(sum(x))
end

function f(x::Array{Missing, 1})
    x = collect(skipmissing(x))
    # do something complicated
    println("removed missings.")
    f(x)
end

f([2, 3, 5])
f([2, 3, 5, missing])
```

I understand that my type is not Missing but `Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}`

When I specify this type, it works in the case above. However, I would like to work with all types (strings, floats etc., not only `Int64`).

I tried

```
function f(x::Array{Missing, 1})
    ...
end
```

But it errors again... Saying that

```
f (generic function with 1 method)
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1})
Closest candidates are:
  f(::Array{Any,1}) at ...
```

**How can I say that I wand the type to be union missings with whatever?**

---

## EDIT (reformulation)

Let's have these 4 vectors and two functions dealing with strings and numbers.

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3]
x2 = [1, 2, 3, missing]
x3 = ["1", "2", "3"]
x4 = ["1", "2", "3", missing]


function f(x::Array{<:Number,1})
    println(sum(x))
end
function f(x::Array{String,1})
    println(join(x))
end
```

`f(x)` doesn't work for x2 and x3, because they are of type `Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}` and `Array{Union{Missing, String},1}`, respectively.

It is possible to have *only one* function that detects whether the vector contains missings, removes them and then deals appropriately with it.

for instance:

```
function f(x::Array{Any, 1})
    x = collect(skipmissing(x))
    print("removed missings")
    f(x)
end
```

But this doesn't work because `Any` indicates a mixed type (e.g., strings and nums) and does not mean string OR numbers or whatever.

---

## EDIT 2 Partial fix

This works:

```
function f(x::Array)
    x = collect(skipmissing(x))
    print("removed missings")
    f(x)
end
```

[But how, then, to specify the shape (number of dimensions) of the array...? (this might be an unrelated topic though)]

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the following way:

```
function f(x::Vector{<:Number})
    # do something complicated
    println("no missings.")
    println(sum(x))
end

function f(x::Vector{Union{Missing,T}}) where {T<:Number}
    x = collect(skipmissing(x))
    # do something complicated
    println("removed missings.")
    f(x)
end
```

and now it works:

```
julia> f([2, 3, 5])
no missings.
10

julia> f([2, 3, 5, missing])
removed missings.
no missings.
10
```

**EDIT:**

I will try to answer the questions raised (if I miss something please add a comment).

First `Vector{Union{Missing, <:Number}}` is the same as `Vector{Union{Missing, Number}}` because of the scoping rules as [tibL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352188/tibl) indicated as `Vector{Union{Missing, <:Number}}` translates to `Array{Union{Missing, T} where T<:Number,1}` and `where` clause is inside `Array`.

Second (here I am not sure if this is what you want). I understand you want the following behavior:

```
julia> g(x::Array{>:Missing,1}) = "$(eltype(x)) allows missing"
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> g(x::Array{T,1}) where T = "$(eltype(x)) does not allow missing"
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> g([1,2,3])
"Int64 does not allow missing"

julia> g([1,2,missing])
"Union{Missing, Int64} allows missing"

julia> g(["a",'a'])
"Any allows missing"

julia> g(Union{String,Char}["a",'a'])
"Union{Char, String} does not allow missing"
```

Note the last two line - although `["a", 'a']` does not contain missing the array has `Any` element type so it might contain missing. The last case excludes it.

Also you can see that you could change the second parameter of `Array{T,N}` to something else to get a different dimensionality.

Also this example works because the first method, as more specific, catches all cases that allow `Missing` and a second method, as more general, catches what is left (i.e. essentially what does not allow `Missing`).

Comment: it does, however if you try to write `f(x::Vector{Union{Missing, <:Number}})` it doesn't which I believe is what the OP is unclear about?

Comment: Awesome! but how to include also the String type? (assuming that the first function doesn't return sum but whatever else compatible with strings). I tried `where{T<:Any]` but that fails also... And @tibL raised a good point

Comment: @DominiqueMakowski `Any` type also includes the `Missing` type, so you could then just write a function which takes `Vector{Any}` (no Union needed)

Comment: So it isn't possible to specify "any which contains missings" then?

Comment: E.g.: `v = [1, "hello", missing]` is a `Vector{Any}`. You can do `foo(x::Vector{Any}) = length(collect(skipmissing(x)))` and `foo(v)` will return `2`

Comment: (following up there for my first comment https://discourse.julialang.org/t/union-of-missing-and-number/13834), there is a difference of type scope between `foo(x::Vector{Union{Missing, T}}) where T<:Number` and 
`foo(x::Vector{Union{Missing, T} where T<:Number})`

Comment: I literally clicked on the question thinking "hm I wonder how Bogumił answered this"  xD