# Julia: Template functions to accept multiple array types

Tags: arrays, function, templates, julia, type-promotion

I'm trying to maintain code reusability whilst using the `Array` type, but am unsure of how to proceed without allowing "illegal" types through. Example functionality:

```
foo = function(x::Array{Number,2})
    print(x)
end

foo([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9])
# 15

foo([1 2 3])
# MethodError: no method matching (::Array{Int64,1})
# Closest candidate is (::Array{Number,2})

foo(["alpha" "beta"; "pi" "rho"])
# MethodError: no method matching (::Array{String,2})
# Closest candidate is (::Array{Number,2})
```

However, the first example, `foo([1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9])` comes back with `MethodError: no method matching (::Array{Int64,2})` despite `(::Array{Number,2})` theoretically being a valid promotion. I don't want to have to manually convert for every function call; nor do I want to have to declare all arrays to be of the `Array{Number,2}` type. I know that I could instead replace the function call with:

```
foo = function(x::Array)
    print(x)
end
```

However, this allows arrays of any dimensionality and type into the function. The only other alternative I can think of is to add boilerplate code where I initially allow any and all arrays in, check their typing and size manually, and go from there, but this feels inelegant.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. (Note: I am using Julia 0.6.3)

Comment: In case you're not aware: you are not defining ordinary functions here, but anonymous functions. So if you try to add a new method, you will just overwrite the old one. The syntax for defining an ordinary function/method is `function foo(x::MyType)   ....  end`. Or the 'one-liner' version: `foo(...) = ...`. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/ for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Matrix{<:Number}` instead of `Array{Number, 2}` as type restriction and all will work (also `Array{<:Number, 2}` would work).

In short `Matrix{Int64}` is not subtype of `Matrix{Number}`, but is a subtype of `Matrix{T} where {T<:Number}` which can be expressed as `Matrix{<:Number}` if you do not use `T` in the body of the function.

The Julia manual here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.4/manual/types/#Parametric-Abstract-Types-1 and here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.4/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1 describes in detail how subtyping in parametric types works in Julia 0.6. Then I think that you can check out this recent SO question [Julia: creating a method for Any vector with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950256/julia-creating-a-method-for-any-vector-with-missing-values/51950470) to understand how more complex cases of subtyping can be handled.